# Unable to decode response

Tags: php, json, decode

i'm having a issue decoding a array from a API and was wondering if anyone could help me out.

```
{
"status": "200",
"response": {
    "onlineId": "psn",
    "plus": 0
}
```

I'm trying to echo the 'plus'

```
$hasplus = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://tusticles.com/psn/api?psn=".$id)) -> {'response->plus'};
```

Does anyone know why it's not working, also i'm still learning and fairly new to PHP.
Thanks

Comment: `->response->plus` (without brackets and single quotes)

Comment: Like this?
`$hasplus = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://tusticles.com/psn/api?psn=".$id)) -> response->plus;`

Comment: I fixed it, thank you dude! :)

Comment: It doesn't matter from where you get the json. Json is json no matter how you get it. When you decode it look at the structure you get with `print_r(json_decode($json));`. Then you see how you have to access the data.